# MSP430G2553: ISR not triggering when I2CTX-Flag is set

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, interrupts, msp430

So I need to get an I2C up and running. To do so the µC relies on ISR's to push data byte by byte onto the data-line. So far so good I programmed my functions and ISR's to transmit and receive data. I enabled the Global Interrupt and the interrupts from the I2C, that i need for functioning. I can also visualize (via LCD) that the Interrupt Flag (say UCB0TXIFG, for transmission) is internally set.

Here's my problem: The interrupt just doesn't trigger.
What I'm after is something that i have missed, that is normally done, but i forgot. I have a lot of programming experience and I had ISR's on Pins up and running.

If anyone has any idea, i would appreciate.

Regards, Steve
Code down below.

**MAIN**:

```
int main(void) {
    // initialize MSP430 and its Ports...
    initMSP();
    if (port_init(8, 2) || port_init(8, 3) || port_init(8, 1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    // initialize the LCD
    lcd_init();
    peep();
    // Initialize the I2C-Hardware with correct address
    i2c_init(0x48); // initialize I2C with Address for the PCF8591T
    __enable_interrupt();
    peep();
    i2c_write(2, "Tÿ", 1); // Write something to bus. <Tÿ> is 0x54FF.
    lcd_putMsg("It's over...");
    while (1) {
        peep2();
        peep2();
    }
}
```

Comments:

- peep-Functions just let an LED blink.
- LCD works.
- Port-Initialization works also.

**I2C**:

```
void i2c_init (unsigned char addr) {
    // initiate pins for use with I2C
    set_pin(6, 1, USCI);
    set_pin(7, 1, USCI);
    // Set I2C in reset state (hard)
    UCB0CTL1 |=  0x01;   // generate Software reset (!all current progress in transmission/reception is lost!)
    // Set up SMCLK Clock (SMLCK = MCLK = 16MHz => Divider for I2C is 160 for 100 kHz)
    BCSCTL2  &= ~0x0F;   // Sets DCO-Resistor to internal, SMCLK Divider to 1, and select DCOCLK for SMCLK
    // Set up I2C Interface Hardware
    UCB0CTL0  =  0x0F;   // 7-bit-mode, single-master, master mode, I2C-mode, synchronous
    UCB0CTL1 |=  0x81;   // SMCLK-Clock, I2C in Reset-State (Bits 6-1 are for online controlling)
    UCB0BR0   =  0xA0;   // Baudrate control register 0 + 1 (Baudrate = BR0 + BR1 * 256)
    UCB0BR1   =  0x00;   // for I2C the baudrate defines a clock prescaler, thus => 16MHz / 100kHz = 160 = 0xA0
    UCB0I2CIE =  0x04;   // only enable interrupt "UCNACKIFG" on NACK received.
    UCB0I2COA =  0x8004; // Don't respond to general call, Address of device is 0x04
    UCB0I2CSA =  0x0000 | (addr & 0x7F); // first chop eventually left MSB of <addr> then convert it to 16 bits.
    UC0IE    |=  0x0C;   // enable ISRs for UCB0TXIFG (Transmit) and UCB0RXIFG (Receive)
    IFG2     &= ~0x0C;   // kill all pending interrupts.
    // Activate I2C on Extension Board
    set_pin(3, 1, HIGH); // Activate I2C on Extension Board. (e.g. Connect XSDA/-SCL to I2C-Lines)
    // Release I2C from reset
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~0x01;   // Set Reset-Bit to Zero
    // Printing initialization message.
    (*print)("I2C initialized.Address: 0x");
    char ret0 = 'Y';
    char ret1 = 'Y';
    charToHex(addr & 0x7F, &ret0, &ret1);
    lcd_putChar(ret1);
    lcd_putChar(ret0);
    return;
}


/* only registers applicable from here:
 * UCB0CTL1 & ( BIT4 (UCTR)      | BIT2 (UCTXSTP)   | BIT1 (UCTXSTT) )
 * UC0IFG2  & ( BIT3 (UCB0TXIFG) | BIT2 (UCB0RXIFG) )
 * UCB0STAT & ( BIT4 (UCBBUSY)   | BIT3 (UCNACKIFG) )
 * */

unsigned char i2c_write(unsigned char length, unsigned char * txData, unsigned char stop) {
    lcd_putMsg("Waiting...      UCB0TXIFG is "); // Debug Message.
    if (IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) {
        lcd_putNumber(1);
    } else {
        lcd_putNumber(0);
    }
    peep();
    // Before writing, you should always check if the last STOP-condition has already been sent.
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);
    transferFinished = 0; // Reset Software Flag
    // rw_mem is a volatile container to hand necessary data
    // to ISR and back to MAIN; initialized here
    rw_mem.lenght = length;
    rw_mem.stop = stop;
    rw_mem.currByte = 0;
    rw_mem.txData = txData;
    rw_mem.outcome = 0;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR; // Set Transmitter-Mode
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT; // Start Protocol
    // Here MSP430 should jump immediately into ISR for UCB0TXIFG (Family Guide S.460)
    while(!transferFinished) { // Wait for transfer to be finished.
        peep(); // Peep helps determine if UC is stuck...
        lcd_putMsg("Waiting...      UCB0TXIFG is "); // Debug Message.
        if (IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) {
            lcd_putNumber(1);
        } else {
            lcd_putNumber(0);
        }
    }
    return rw_mem.outcome;
}

void i2c_read(unsigned char length, unsigned char * rxData) {
    // Before writing, you should always check if the last STOP-condition has already been sent.
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);


    if (length == 1) {
        // Todo: If you only want to receive one byte, you instantly have to write a STOP-condition
        // after the START-condition got sent.
    }

    // Wait for transfer to be finished.
    // Info: In TI's sample code, low-power mode statements are inserted,
    // also waiting for the transfer to be finished.
    while(!transferFinished);
}

// Vector for UCB0(T/R)XIFG (only in I2C)
// UCB0TXIFG    / TRANSMIT
// UCB0RXIFG    / RECEIVE
#pragma vector = USCIAB0TX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0TX_ISR(void)
{ // first check which interrupt actually triggered the ISR
    lcd_putMsg("Heading to ISR"); // Debug
    if (IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) { // TX triggered ISR
        // check were the writing process it at exactly
        if (rw_mem.currByte >= rw_mem.lenght) { // length equals currByte => All bytes were written
            transferFinished = 1; // Transfer is finished
            rw_mem.outcome = 0; // Outcome of transfer was positive (all bytes transferred and acknowledged)
            if (rw_mem.stop) {UCB0CTL1 |=  UCTXSTP;} // Initiate Stop if appropriate
            IFG2  &= ~UCB0TXIFG; // Clear ISR-Flag
        } else { // in the other case, bytes are left
            UCB0TXBUF = rw_mem.txData[rw_mem.currByte]; // write next byte to buffer
            rw_mem.currByte++; // iterate counter on step up
            // I did not clearly see, from Family Guide,
            // if Flag-Reset is done by software or hardware,
            // though it says not explicitly to do so
            IFG2  &= ~UCB0TXIFG; // Clear ISR-Flag
        }
    }
    if (IFG2 & UCB0RXIFG) { // RX triggered ISR
        transferFinished = 1;
    }
lcd_putMsg("Leaving ISR"); // Debug
peep();
__delay_cycles(160000000); // 10 seconds
}

// Vector for status Flags (only in I2C)
// UCNACKIFG    / NACK
// UCSTPIFG     / STOP
// UCSTTIFG     / START
// UCALIFG      / ARBITRATION LOST
#pragma vector = USCIAB0RX_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCIAB0RX_ISR(void)
{ // as of now, NACK is the only possible flag. Implementing if-loop none-the-less for redudancy's sake
    if (UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) { // NACK triggered ISR
        rw_mem.outcome = 1; // Outcome of Transfer was negative. (NACK)
        transferFinished = 1; // transfer is UNSUCCESSFULLY finished.
        UCB0CTL1 |=  UCTXSTP; // Initiate Stop
        UCB0STAT &= ~UCNACKIFG; // Resetting flag, again guide is unclear.
    }
}
```

So, the problem is, that decpite the flag UCB0TXIFG being 1 its interrupt UCB0TXIE enabled and the GIE enabled, The vector USCIAB0TX_ISR does not trigger.

Would appreciate any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Please show an oscilloscope or logic analyzer trace of the I²C lines.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it in the meantime…

My problem was, that I had reset the hold bit (UCB0CTL1 &= ~0x01) after enabling the Interrupts (IFG2) in the I2c_init function, which where then reseted and thus not triggering.

So to solve the problem just switch the
Statement UCB0CTL1 &= ~0x01; to before UCB0I2CIE =  0x04;

You can also look up section 13.1.7 of the family guide for more info on that.

Cheers guys.